# Customize full screen barcode scanner of XDK to have additional buttons like Review/Edit on Layout

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk, intel-xdk-contacts

We are building a Android APP which needs us to customize the Scanner page.

The description on the document says:

> "This function will open a full-scren QR code reader in an
>   application. Once it successfully reads a QR code, or the reader is
>   cancelled, the appMobi.device.barcode.scan event is called."

We want to add three buttons on left hand side or right hand side of the scanner screen to ensure we give some additional functionality required for our project, is their a way to do this?

Btw XDK bar-code scanner is awesome, just want to customize and add few buttons, any other way to have a translucent layer for button or any direction/suggestions are really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible at this time.  As far as I can tell, when `intel.xdk.device.scanBarcode` is called, it takes over the entire screen and no styling or modification is possible.  According to the [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493036):

> This function will open a full-scren QR code reader in an application. Once it successfully reads a QR code, or the reader is cancelled, the intel.xdk.device.barcode.scan event is called.

There doesn't appear to be anyway to modify it (e.g. by adding buttons) that I can see.